# Completely customize admin menu without plugin

Tags: wordpress, menu, admin

Basically what I want is to remove most of the admin menu and replace it with my own, without using a plugin. But I'd also like it to stay after a wp update.

Is this a possibility and if so, how?
Or is it just a million times easier to make the plugin and be done with it?

EDIT
In /wp-admin there is a menu on the left side. I won't be needing most of the menu and therefor don't want others to see or edit stuff in there(because the only thing that will happen is it will break the site). So I want to remove the unnecesary menu items and add relevant menu items. (It's about Posts, Pages, Media etc)

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more on what exactly do you want to replace

Comment: I've edited my question and formulated it a little better.

Comment: You have to remove only menu ?

Comment: Yes, only remove some of the standard menu items and add new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others already mentioned you could use the function `remove_menu_page`, but you still have to put this code somewhere.
If you really don't want to create a plugin you could add this code to the `functions.php` file of your theme.

In my opinion it's not theme related code, so it would be better to put it in a custom plugin. And it's really easy, here's a video on how to create one within minutes:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9Nhb1KX7vM

In your case it would look something like:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:    Custom Admin Menu
Version:        1.0.0
Description:    My Custom Admin Menu
Author:         Peter van der Net
*/
if (!function_exists('my_custom_admin_menu')):

    function my_custom_admin_menu(){
        remove_menu_page('index.php');
        remove_menu_page('plugins.php');
        remove_menu_page('users.php');
        // etcetera..
    }

    add_action('admin_menu', 'my_custom_admin_menu');

endif;

/*?>*/
```

Put this code in a file named `custom-admin-menu.php` in the folder `wp-content/plugins`. And then activate the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

although it is not necessary and there are a lot of other ways to secure your wordPress install but still you can refer the below page and this will answer your question

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page

Hope this helps

Take care and Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

This function should be called on the admin_menu action hook.

```
   <?php 
  function custom_menu_page_removing() {
      remove_menu_page( $menu_slug );
   }
  add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_menu_page_removing' );
  ?>
```

Removes every menu for all users.

```
  <?php
  function remove_menus(){
   remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );                  //Dashboard
   remove_menu_page( 'jetpack' );                    //Jetpack* 
   remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );                   //Posts
   remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );                 //Media
   remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );    //Pages
   remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );          //Comments
   remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );                 //Appearance
   remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );                //Plugins
   remove_menu_page( 'users.php' );                  //Users
   remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );                  //Tools
   remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );        //Settings

   }
  add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
  ?>
```

For detailed explanation: [URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_menu)